# How to interpret mixed effects logistic regression of 2 categorical predictors?

Tags: r, categorical-data, multilevel-analysis, predictor

if *A* is the Group reference level & *Noun* is the Class reference level, is this summary telling us GroupC is significantly different from GroupA **at only the level of nouns**(intercept)? Or is it an overall sig difference considering all levels of the second categorical predictor?

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The estimate of Group C tells you the predicted difference between Group A and Group C, at the reference level of Class (Noun). Likewise the estimate of Group B shows you the predicted difference between Group A and Group B, at the reference level of Class (Noun). The estimate of Class (Adjective) tells you the predicted difference between Noun and Adjective, at the reference level of Group (A).

If you want to look at the differences between Group levels under adjective Class level, you should interact Group with Class.

Comment: Thank you for putting me on the right track. I am interested in the  predicted differences between groups regardless of class. Do I have to dummy code Class for this?

Comment: You need to change the contrasts for Class. Sum or deviation coding should be fine.

Comment: I could not know how to achieve that

Comment: Consider this guide for an explanation (http://talklab.psy.gla.ac.uk/tvw/catpred/) and this guide for the implementation (http://www.mypolyuweb.hk/~sjpolit/coding_schemes.html).

Comment: I applied this coding, but could not get its aim since the data always show the 2nd variable is a reference level at the intercept? Is it because the level will become 0 or 1?

Comment: As mentioned in the second link (where they also show you the code), treatment coding reveals simple effects (what you currently have and the (default) contrasts that I described in my answer) and deviation coding reveals main effects (what I assume you desire for Class). If you deviation code Class, the intercept will no longer represent the predicted value for Group A and Class Noun, it will represent the predicted value for Group A at "mean" of Class. The intercept value should therefore be somewhat different from what you had in your original question.